# What are the best ways to use a "start here" sign

Tags: keyboard, indicator

I gotta show to the user where to start using a special  virtual keyboard, what are the best ways to do it ? Where to put a button to close the sign ? What is the best positioning to it ?

Comment: This is a very thin question that will be hard to answer without more detail.  Can you elaborate and give more context?

Comment: I'm building a service that has a virtual keyboard, but a bit different of the common virtual keyboards we're used to see, so I would like to show to the user where it can start clicking to show how the keyboard works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think you could borrow pages from any software with an unfamiliar UI, like what Autodesk Maya or Adobe Photoshop does - most of them have little pop-ups that hover over the actual places (Maya) OR a single pop-up upon opening the software with screenshots of where to go and explaining specific functionality (Adobe products).